# Use custom video effect in UWP

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, uwp, cordova-win10

First of all - my native language is not eanglish, sorry for posssible mistakes.

I need to use my own video effect for MediaCapture, made this for WS 8.1 and WP 8.1, than I start porting it to Win 10 at this moment start problems. My Video effect made as runtime component(dll), in this module I've got ActivatableClass and  it is working!For win 8.1 I modified the manifest and add reference for my component, AddEffectAsync method I used with this parameters

```
m_mediaCaptureMgr->AddEffectAsync(Windows::Media::Capture::MediaStreamType::VideoPreview,"OcvComponent.SmileDetector",nullptr)
```

In Win 10 I've got crash in similary code

```
_mediaCapture->AddVideoEffectAsync(ref new Effects::VideoEffectDefinition("OcvComponent.SmileDetector"), Capture::MediaStreamType::VideoPreview)
```

I am already try old, well work method like this, the result is also crash

```
_mediaCapture->AddEffectAsync(Capture::MediaStreamType::VideoPreview,"OcvComponent.SmileDetector", nullptr)
```

Manifest in both cases i modify with this

```
<Extensions>
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
  <InProcessServer>
    <Path>OcvComponent.dll</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="OcvComponent.SmileDetector" ThreadingModel="both" />
  </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

App crashed with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKgS0.jpg) message

This crash appear befor ActivatableClass constructor used, so breakpoint don't help me.

Also I should tell that the app in wich I call videoeffect  for sample taken from github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraVideoStabilization/cpp (sorry for incorrect link, not enough reputation), and I don't  understand why but I can not add reference for this project to my component normally i've got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMutk.jpg), so I modify project file in text redactor with this

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\OcvComponent\OcvComponent.vcxproj">
  <Project>{E84D5530-529F-49B4-811C-3D7FE0902B7E}</Project>
</ProjectReference>
```

I think this things can be connected.

Please help me to solve this problem
use C++ language, Visual Studio 2015,Win 10

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is still interesting to you.. but maybe to somebody else.
Found this here:
https://english.r2d2rigo.es/2016/03/10/creating-custom-video-effects-in-uwp-apps/

TLDR:

- use a runtime component library (not any other project type)
- make your effect sealed
- you don't need to change the manifest anymore

cheers,